# class sensor_msgs.CompressedImage, unresolved supertypes: org.ros.internal.message.Message> Task:app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug

Tags: ros-kinetic, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't compile my Android Kotlin Project because I get the following 'Kotlin compiler' error when gradle compiles:

```
Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure 
you have the required dependencies in the classpath: class 
sensor_msgs.CompressedImage, unresolved supertypes: 
org.ros.internal.message.Message> Task:app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug
```

This is a simple test project that has the bare minimum code using http://wiki.ros.org/shield_teleop as a boilerplate. I removed the joystick code but left the camera code.

A am using ROS Kinetic Ubuntu on the robot, Android 8.0 on the app.

Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="com.company.roscameratest">

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" tools:replace="android:icon">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="org.ros.android.MasterChooser" />

        <service android:name="org.ros.android.NodeMainExecutorService" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="org.ros.android.NodeMainExecutorService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle (Project):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.41'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
 }

dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle (Module):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.roscameratest"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force "org.ros.android_core:android_15:0.3.3"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'org.ros.android_core:android_15:0.3.3'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

repositories {
    maven {  url 'https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_mvn_repo/raw/master' }
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329087/class--sensor_msgs.compressedimage,-unresolved-supertypes:--org.ros.internal.message.message%3E-task:app:buildinfogeneratordebug/) by [Tav_PG](https://answers.ros.org/users/43825/tav_pg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2019-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have since resolved this issue.  It is not completely a ROS issue.

I had found the issue was when I changed from AppCompatActivity to RosActivity, so I looked at all controls in the main form to see which classes they were using. Classes were being called in a mix of both android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity and androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity. I moved all my controls in my RosActivity form over from android to android-x and there was no compile error.

---

Originally posted by [Tav_PG](https://answers.ros.org/users/43825/tav_pg/) with karma: 28 on 2019-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0